# Compare two Excel workbooks, and create a new sheet containing the differences

Tags: vba, excel, time-limit-exceeded

I have code that scans and compares two Excel workbooks, and then pastes all of the differences between the two into a new sheet. My code is working properly -
 the only problem is when the Excel workbook contains more than 250,000 rows and 33 columns (i.e. more than 1 million cells). When I start running the macros, Excel hangs and restarts.

How can I improve the performance of these macros so that they will scale properly for large data sets? What should I change or add in my code?

Also, since I am new to writing macros, is there anything else that I should change? I've tried researching on Google and Stack Overflow, but couldn't find much relevant information.

Here is my full code (let me know if you need me to provide more):

```
Public Sub compareWS()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo errorhandler1
'Define workbook and worksheets
Set wb3 = Workbooks("ExcelComp.xlsm")
Set wb3sht1 = wb3.Sheets("difference")
Set wb3sht2 = wb3.Sheets("mapping")
Set wb1 = Workbooks(wb3sht2.Range("A3").Value)
Set wb2 = Workbooks(wb3sht2.Range("B3").Value)
'Format headers of difference worksheet
wb3sht1.Cells.ClearContents

wb3sht1.Range("A1").Value = "WB1 value"
wb3sht1.Range("B1").Value = "WB2 value"
wb3sht1.Range("C1").Value = "WB1 header"
wb3sht1.Range("D1").Value = "WB2 header"
wb3sht1.Range("E1").Value = "GUID 2"
wb3sht1.Range("F1").Value = "GUID 1"

wb3sht1.Range("A1:B1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
wb3sht1.Range("C1:D1").Interior.Color = vbCyan
wb3sht1.Range("E1:F1").Interior.Color = vbYellow

For mappingrow = 7 To wb3sht2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Get workbook and worksheet names in worksheet mapping
    Set wb1sht1 = wb1.Sheets(wb3sht2.Range("A" & mappingrow).Value)
    Set wb2sht1 = wb2.Sheets(wb3sht2.Range("B" & mappingrow).Value)
    'Get the max row and column in two worksheets
    If wb1sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row > 
    wb2sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row Then
        maxrow = wb1sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Else
        maxrow = wb2sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End If

    If wb1sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column > 
wb2sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column Then
        maxcol = wb1sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Else
        maxcol = wb2sht1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    End If
    'Compare two woorksheets cell by cell and mark the difference in 
worksheet difference
    For r = 1 To maxrow
        For c = 1 To maxcol
            If UCase(wb1sht1.Cells(r, c).Text) <> UCase(wb2sht1.Cells(r, 
c).Text) Then
                nextrow = wb3sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                'wb3sht1.Range("A" & nextrow).Value = "'[" & 
wb3sht2.Range("A3").Value & "]" & wb1sht1.Name & "'!" & wb1sht1.Cells(r, 
c).Address
                'wb3sht1.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=wb3sht1.Range("A" & 
nextrow), Address:="", SubAddress:="'[" & wb3sht2.Range("A3").Value & "]" & 
wb1sht1.Name & "'!" & wb1sht1.Cells(r, c).Address
                'wb3sht1.Range("B" & nextrow).Value = "'[" & 
wb3sht2.Range("B3").Value & "]" & wb2sht1.Name & "'!" & wb2sht1.Cells(r, 
c).Address
                'wb3sht1.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=wb3sht1.Range("B" & 
nextrow), Address:="", SubAddress:="'[" & wb3sht2.Range("B3").Value & "]" & 
wb2sht1.Name & "'!" & wb2sht1.Cells(r, c).Address
                wb3sht1.Range("A" & nextrow).Value = wb1sht1.Cells(r, 
c).Value
                wb3sht1.Range("B" & nextrow).Value = wb2sht1.Cells(r, 
c).Value
                wb3sht1.Range("C" & nextrow).Value = wb1sht1.Cells(1, 
c).Value
                wb3sht1.Range("D" & nextrow).Value = wb2sht1.Cells(1, 
c).Value

                wb3sht1.Range("E" & nextrow).Value = wb2sht1.Cells(r, 
1).Value
                wb3sht1.Range("F" & nextrow).Value = wb1sht1.Cells(r, 
1).Value
            End If

       Next c
    Next r
Next mappingrow


wb3sht1.Activate
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

errorhandler1:

End Sub



Public Sub getWB1Name()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo errorhandler1
'Define workbook and worksheets
Set wb3 = Workbooks("ExcelComp.xlsm")
Set wb3sht1 = wb3.Sheets("difference")
Set wb3sht2 = wb3.Sheets("mapping")
Set wb1 = Workbooks(wb3sht2.Range("A3").Value)
Set wb2 = Workbooks(wb3sht2.Range("B3").Value)
startRow = 7

For Each ws In wb1.Sheets
    wb3sht2.Range("A" & startRow).Value = ws.Name
    startRow = startRow + 1
Next ws

errorhandler1:

End Sub



Public Sub getWB2Name()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo errorhandler1
'Define workbook and worksheets
Set wb3 = Workbooks("ExcelComp.xlsm")
Set wb3sht1 = wb3.Sheets("difference")
Set wb3sht2 = wb3.Sheets("mapping")
Set wb1 = Workbooks(wb3sht2.Range("A3").Value)
Set wb2 = Workbooks(wb3sht2.Range("B3").Value)
startRow = 7

For Each ws In wb2.Sheets
    wb3sht2.Range("B" & startRow).Value = ws.Name
    startRow = startRow + 1
Next ws

errorhandler1:

End Sub
```

Comment: To start, you can turn off auto calculation (Manual) since everytime you add a Hyperlink, calculations may take place, and add `DoEvents` just above `Next c` to give Excel a chance to response from UI etc. You may also want to load the ranges Value onto memory and compare within memory instead of calls Range/Cells. Make use of `Application.StatusBar` to hint progress.

Comment: For optimization, you may go with arrays instead of range. at the end, you could paste your result data to range.
for further info, you may check http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx
i haven't checked all your code so if this solution is proper for you though.

Comment: I see no `Dim` in your code. Did you enable `Option Explicit` ? If not, do it !!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you'd want to do is fix those variables.

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant* type that can hold any type of data. While this may be more flexible, it adds processing time to your macro as VBA decides or tests for the type. Additionally, since a Variant can be any type of data, you may miss out on valuable troubleshooting information on *Type Mismatch*

Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mapping")` and instead just use `Mapping`.

On this part -

> ```
> wb3sht1.Range("A1:B1").Interior.Color = vbGreen
> wb3sht1.Range("C1:D1").Interior.Color = vbCyan
> wb3sht1.Range("E1:F1").Interior.Color = vbYellow
> ```

You're using color constants, which, unfortunately, aren't always rendered the same across machines

```
wb3sht1.Range("E1:F1").Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0)
```

Now you guarantee yellow shows up.

When you have a magic number like here

> ```
> For mappingrow = 7 To wb3sht2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

It's sometimes better to make a constant

```
Const MAPPING_BEGIN as Long = 7
mappingLastRow = wb3sht2.Cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For mappingRow = MAPPING_BEGIN to mappingLastRow
```